# When ForkJoinPool ended

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream

I'm trying to figure out when all ForkJoinPool threads have completed their tasks.
I wrote this test app (I used System.out because it is just a quick test app as well as no error checking / handling):

```
public class TestForkJoinPoolEnd {
    private static final Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 5000;
    private static final int SPEED_UP = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(12);
        customThreadPool.submit(
                () -> makeList()
                        .parallelStream()
                        .forEach(TestForkJoinPoolEnd::process));
        enqueue("Theard pool started up");

        int counter = MAX_SIZE + 1;
        while (!customThreadPool.isTerminating()) {
            String s = dequeue();
            if (s != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
                counter--;
            }
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("counter = " + counter);
        System.out.println("isQuiescent = " + customThreadPool.isQuiescent()     + " isTerminating " +
                "= " + customThreadPool.isTerminating() + " isTerminated = "
                + customThreadPool.isTerminated() + " isShutdown =" +     customThreadPool.isShutdown());
    }

    static List<String> makeList() {
        return Stream.generate(() -> makeString())
                .limit(MAX_SIZE)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static String makeString() {
        int leftLimit = 97; // letter 'a'
        int rightLimit = 122; // letter 'z'
        int targetStringLength = 10;
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
            int randomLimitedInt = leftLimit + (int)
                    (random.nextFloat() * (rightLimit - leftLimit + 1));
            buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    static int toSeed(String s) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            sum += s.charAt(i);
        }
        return (sum / SPEED_UP);
    }

    static void process(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(toSeed(s));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sb.append(" slept for ")
                .append((end - start))
                .append(" milliseconds");
        enqueue(sb.toString());
    }

    static void enqueue(String s) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.offer(s);
        }
    }

    static String dequeue() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            return queue.poll();
        }
    }
}
```

This code gets stuck and never finish. If I change the condition of the while loop to `!customThreadPool.isQuiescent()` it terminates the loop with the counter and queue size set at 1.

What should I use to determine when the threads are done?

Comment: An `ExecutorService` does not terminate when no-one called `shutdown()` on it. You are the one supposed to know when you don’t need it anymore. When you want to know about the job’s completion, just use the future returned by the `submit` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ExecutorService` does not terminate itself just because one job (and its sub-jobs) completed. The whole idea behind a thread pool is to be reusable.

So it will only terminate when the application calls `shutdown()` on it.

You can use `isQuiescent()` to find out whether there are no pending jobs, which only works when all submitted jobs belong to your particular task. It’s much cleaner, to use the future returned by `submit` to check the actual job’s completion.

In either case, the completion state of the enqueuing task(s) does not say anything about the queue you are polling. By the time you learn about the end of submissions, you still have to check the queue for pending elements.

Further, it’s recommended to use a thread safe `BlockingQueue` implementation instead of decorating a `LinkedList` with `synchronized` blocks. Together with some other things to clean up, the code would look like:

```
public class TestForkJoinPoolEnd {
    private static final BlockingQueue<String> QUEUE = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 5000;
    private static final int SPEED_UP = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(12);
        ForkJoinTask<?> future = customThreadPool.submit(
            () -> makeList()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .forEach(TestForkJoinPoolEnd::process));
        QUEUE.offer("Theard pool started up");

        int counter = MAX_SIZE + 1;
        while (!future.isDone()) try {
            String s = QUEUE.poll(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (s != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
                counter--;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        for(;;) {
            String s = QUEUE.poll();
            if (s == null) break;
            System.out.println(s);
            counter--;
        }
        System.out.println("counter = " + counter);
        System.out.println("isQuiescent = " + customThreadPool.isQuiescent()     + " isTerminating " +
                "= " + customThreadPool.isTerminating() + " isTerminated = "
                + customThreadPool.isTerminated() + " isShutdown =" +     customThreadPool.isShutdown());

        customThreadPool.shutdown();
    }

    static List<String> makeList() {
        return IntStream.range(0, MAX_SIZE)
            .mapToObj(i -> makeString())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static String makeString() {
        int targetStringLength = 10;
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
            int randomLimitedInt = random.nextInt('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a';
            buffer.append((char) randomLimitedInt);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    static int toSeed(String s) {
        return s.chars().sum() / SPEED_UP;
    }

    static void process(String s) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(toSeed(s));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        QUEUE.offer(s + " slept for " + (end - start)/1000000 + " milliseconds");
    }
}
```

If your `sleep` call at the receiving end was supposed to simulate some workload rather than to wait for new items, you can also use

```
int counter = MAX_SIZE + 1;
while (!future.isDone()) {
    String s = QUEUE.poll();
    if (s != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        counter--;
    }
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

but the logic doesn’t change. After `future.isDone()` returned `true`, we have to re-check for pending elements in the queue. We’re only guaranteed that no new items will arrive, not that the queue is already empty.

As a side note, the `makeString()` method could be improved further to

```
static String makeString() {
    int targetStringLength = 10;
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(targetStringLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < targetStringLength; i++) {
        int randomLimitedInt = random.nextInt('a', 'z' + 1);
        buffer.append((char)randomLimitedInt);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

or even

```
static String makeString() {
    int targetStringLength = 10;
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current()
        .ints(targetStringLength, 'a', 'z'+1)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very well explained answer, plus some bonus learning opportunity for me. Personally I'm not mad about `for(;;)` I'd rather have a `do {} while(someCondition)`

Comment: @TungstenX I don’t like it either, however, it’s a recurring problem to have the condition in the middle of the loop body. There alternative ways to write it, but neither is really much better.